# how to get index number of class when button is clicked

Tags: javascript

I want to get the class index number of a button when it is clicked.

Eg: When 1st button is clicked it should display index 0, when 2nd button is clicked it should display index 1 and when 3rd button is clicked it should display index 2...

Code:

```
<button class="btn">Click Me</button>

<button class="btn">Click Me</button>

<button class="btn">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: the event that you attach passes an event variable that will contain everything about the element that was clicked `document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click', evtInfo => { /* check evtInfo properties */ })`

Comment: use `onclick` in the `button` element, and you can use `data-index` to get the attribute from the `ev.target` like: `<button class="btn" data-index="0" onclick="handleClick(this)" >Click Me</button>` and get data with `element.getAttribute('data-card')` or `ev.target.getAttribute('data-card')`